# getting secondary name using sub query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, 1st table holds the categories list and 2nd table holds the profile information along with 1st table category id as a foreign key. As follow

Table1

```
id  CATEGORY 
1    first   
2    second
```

Table2

```
id  CATEGORY name     phone
1    2       John    9999999999
```

how to retrieve table 2 records along with category name (not id:2 as shown in table 2)

I tried this,

```
SELECT category, name, phone FROM table2;
```

I need to see following line as result

```
second, john, 9999999999
```

get me out of this step, thanks in advance.

Comment: no subquery required. you need to learn about [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `JOIN`, which means you "combine" two tables by linking rows from one table to rows from another table based on some criterion.

In your case, the criterion is that the value of `CATEGORY` in `table2` must equal the value of `ID` in `table1`, which is expressed as follows:

```
SELECT table1.category,
       table2.name,
       table2.phone
FROM   table2
JOIN   table1
  ON   table2.category = table1.id
```

If needed, you can add a `WHERE` clause to limit the result to specific rows, e.g. `WHERE table1.id = 9999999999` would filter the rows that have category 9999999999.

Comment: Doesn't limit the results to what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks @mthmulders for the quick response, helped me.

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT t1.category, t2.name, t2.phone 
FROM table2 AS t2 
JOIN table1 AS t1 
ON t1.id = t2.category
```

Comment: Good, but doesn't limit to the one record the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an INNER JOIN and get the category from the Table 1, like this:

```
SELECT tb1.category, tb2.name, tb2.phone 
FROM table2 tb2
INNER JOIN table1 tb1 on tb2.category = tb1.id
WHERE tb2.id = 1;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't limit the results to what the OP asked for.

Comment: the OP said "how to retrieve table 2 records along with category name (not id:2 as shown in table 2)", he does not specify which records he wants, he just added a example of how he wants the results.

Comment: The OP said "I need to see following line as result *second, john, 9999999999*". Or maybe *I* mis-read that. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: i think he was just giving an example, but i'm adding an WHERE clause to my answer just in case you're right :), thanks!

Comment: `"need to see" !== "need an example"`